# Visual Studio Reports (RDLC): html tags are ignored

Tags: html, rdlc, reportviewer

I'm using Visual Studio Reports to render some HTML text, using the built-in option to set a placeholder as html text.

Now, everything works but one thing: I have a problem with `<font>` tags. In particular, if I set a size in points, like:

```
<font size="5pt"> Some text </font>
```

or even:

```
<font style="font-size:5pt">5pt line</font>
```

This gets ignored completely.
I should note that both the above examples work fine in web browsers, and that `<font>` is one of the officially supported tags in RDLC. So what's going on here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **font** tag doesn't seem to be fully supported, but using a **span** tag will work.  Set the following expression as the Value of the placeholder and it will render correctly:

```
="<span style='font-size:5pt'> Some text </span>"
```

Also, ensure that the 'Markup Type' is set the 'HTML' in the placeholder properties.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645967.aspx

Comment: I know it works with spans + "style" tags, but my problem was that the original HTML had "font" tags that I couldn't change. In the end I ended up doing some post-processing, manually changing font tags to spans in code. But my question is: documentation says the font tag is supported... now, the only use of a font tag is to change font, so if RDLC does not support that... in what way do they claim that the font tag is "supported"?